# Using $slice when finding data from subdocument's array

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I need to get the latest entry from subdocument's array from a document defined by "_id".

The document looks like this:

```
{
"_id": "nex67",
"ownedparts": [
    {
        "id": "tool1",
        "history": [
            {
                "time": ISODate("2016-06-07T09:12:54.015Z"),
                "value": 300
            },
            {
                "time": ISODate("2016-06-07T09:12:54.015Z"),
                "value": 240
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "id": "screw1",
        "history": [
            {
                "time": ISODate("2016-06-07T09:12:54.015Z"),
                "value": 500
            }
        ]
    }
]}
```

With this query i get full history of "tool1":

```
db.users.find(  
{
    "_id": "nex67",
    "ownedparts.id": "tool1"
},  { "ownedparts.history.$": 1 })
```

And with this command i do get the latest entry, but it returns them from both "tool1" and "screw1":

```
db.users.find(  
{"_id": "nex67"},
{"ownedparts.history": { $slice: -1 }})
```

So basically i need help combining these queries so that i can get the latest history entry from nex67's tool1.

The result i need should look like this:

```
{
    "_id" : "nex67",
    "ownedparts" : [
            {
                    "id" : "tool1",
                    "history" : [
                            {
                                    "time" : ISODate("2016-06-07T09:12:54.015Z"),
                                    "value" : 240
                            }
                    ]
            }
    ]}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The optimal way to do this is in MongoDB 3.2 using the [`$arrayElemAt`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/arrayElemAt/) and the [`$filter`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/filter/) operators.

```
db.users.aggregate(
    [
        { "$match": { "_id": "nex67", "ownedparts.id": "tool1" } }, 
        { "$project": { 
            "ownedparts": { 
                "$let": { 
                    "vars": { 
                        "el": { 
                            "$arrayElemAt": [ 
                                { "$filter": { 
                                    "input": "$ownedparts", 
                                    "as": "own", 
                                    "cond": { "$eq": [ "$$own.id", "tool1" ] }
                                }}, 
                                0 
                            ]
                        }
                    }, 
                    "in": { 
                        "id": "$$el.id", 
                        "history": { "$arrayElemAt": [ "$$el.history", -1 ] } 
                    }
                }
            }
        }}
    ]
)
```

which produces:

```
{ 
    "_id" : "nex67", 
    "ownedparts" : { 
        "id" : "tool1", 
        "history" : {
            "time" : ISODate("2016-06-07T09:12:54.015Z"), 
            "value" : 240 
        } 
    }
}
```

Comment: nice one - perfect combination of `$filter` inside `$arrayElemAt`!

Answer (score 1):

As we have nested arrays - it is not a trivial problem.
To solve that we need to use aggregation framework, to select first record `project`, then `unwind` array to reduce nesting and last `project2` to reconstruct document as required. `match` is used as a filter to reuduce amount of document in process.

```
var match = {
    $match : {
        "_id" : "nex67"
    }
}

var project = {
    $project : {
        _id : 1,
        ownedpartsFirst : {
            $slice : ["$ownedparts", 1]
        }
    }
}
var unwind = {
    $unwind : "$ownedpartsFirst"
}
var project2 = {
    $project : {
        _id : 1,
        ownedparts :
        [{
                id : "$ownedpartsFirst.id",
                history : {
                    $slice : ["$ownedpartsFirst.history", -1]
                }
            }
        ]
    }
}

db.collectionName.aggregate([match, project, unwind, project2])
```

> output:

```
{
    "_id" : "nex67",
    "ownedparts" : [ 
        {
            "id" : "tool1",
            "history" : [ 
                {
                    "time" : ISODate("2016-06-07T09:12:54.015Z"),
                    "value" : 240.0
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: this works too, but i'm choosing the one that uses $arrayElemAt as answer because it seems more optimal.

Answer (score -1):

try with this

```
db.users.find(  
         {"_id": "nex67"},
         {"ownedparts.$.history": { $slice: -1 }})
```

And you have a problem with this consult

```
 db.users.find(  
{
         "_id": "nex67",
         "ownedparts.id": "tool1"
},  { "ownedparts.history.$": 1 })
```

The simbol $ is between ownedparts and history to get the element from you array

```
 db.users.find(  
{
         "_id": "nex67",
         "ownedparts.id": "tool1"
},  { "ownedparts.$.history": 1 })
```

Comment: this returns all sub array elements